# Android App is not showing up in the App Drawer

Tags: android

I've been looking at it from multiple angles and tried the solutions suggested from SO. Nothing seems to be working. The icon is a drawable, I've added the suggested actions to my intent-filter and still the app is not showing up when I install it.

Where is the problem in my Manifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="lite.hattrick.main"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="liteTrick"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >

        <service android:name="lite.hattrick.services.LiteTrickService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data
                    android:host="whodunit"
                    android:scheme="callback" >
                </data>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".BaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="lite.hattrick.players.HattrickPlayerActivity"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: its only a guess but what is if you delete this line: <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> or switch order so that this: <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> is the first line in the intent-filter

Answer (score 1):

Split those in two intent filters:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <data
          android:host="whodunit"
          android:scheme="callback" >
     </data>
</intent-filter>
```

See if it works.

Comment: As expected the application now shows in the drawer but the callback no longer works.